# Run some code if any exception occur and to a specific exception

Tags: python, exception, python-2.7, pygame

I have this function. My pygame's text to rectangle converter.

```py
def text_to_rect(text, name='default'):
    try:
        font  = load.text_style[name]['font']
        aa    = load.text_style[name]['aa']
        color = load.text_style[name]['color']
    except NameError:
        font_path = pygame.font.get_default_font()
        font = pygame.font.Font(font_path, 24)
        aa = 1
        color = (0,0,0)
        if not name=='default':
            text = text+'(ERROR: Global load object not defined.)'
    except KeyError:
        font_path = pygame.font.get_default_font()
        font = pygame.font.Font(font_path, 24)
        aa = 1
        color = (0,0,0)
        if not name=='default':
            text = text+'(ERROR: '+name+' text style does not exist.)'
    return font.render(text,aa,color)
```

In two **except** blocks there are 4 lines of the same code. I want to run these 4 lines if any exception occurs, then rest to a specific exception.

Comment: I am no expert in Python or Object-Orientated programming, but you might want to look at Polymorphism, and making it so that a certain error extends a different error.  I am sorry that I cannot give specific examples, but I remember this kinda thing when I used to do Java....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually combine exceptions into one statement:

```
try:
    #code that you expect errors from

except KeyError, NameError:
    #exception code

except:
    #Of course, you can also do a naked except to catch all
    #exceptions,
    #But if you're forced to do this, you're probably
    #doing something wrong. This is bad coding style.
```

*EDIT*
For your case, if you want your code execution to depend on the error caught, do this:

```
try:
    #Code to try
except (KeyError, NameError) as e:
    #Code to execute in either case
    if isinstance(e, KeyError):
        #code to execute if error is KeyError
    else:
        #code to execute if error is NameError
```

Comment: Ok. So if I get **except** **KeyError**, **NameError**: block, how to check which one occur?

Comment: In about of neked except. Is good way to catch exception that way and re-raise it.
`except:`
`# do rollback or somthing`
`# log that the exception occour`
`raise`

Comment: It would be semantically identical to the above. If your going to be doing this a lot, however, I would turn the above into a decorator.